# How to get the logged in username in decoratored JSP page using sitemesh and Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, sitemesh

I'm using sitemesh framework to decorate the header.jsp file. Now I can able to get the logged in username in my home.jsp page using following code block.

```
  <security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
     authenticated as <security:authentication property="principal.username" />
  </security:authorize>
```

But Now want to show the username in header.jsp file. I'm using sitemesh for decorating the home page

header.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
.......

    <body>
     .............
         <security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
               authenticated as <security:authentication property="principal.username" />
        </security:authorize>

        <decorator:body/>
    ................
```

and my decorator.xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/WEB-INF/decorators">
<excludes>
    <pattern>/resources/*</pattern>
    <pattern>/images/*</pattern>
</excludes>

<decorator name="header" page="header.jsp">
    <pattern>*/*</pattern>
</decorator>
</decorators>
```

I couldn't get the username in header.jsp file.

Please help me.